# VS 2010 - Adding additional projects to Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

At work we have just upgraded from VS2008 to VS2010 (keeping up with the times, I know). In VS2008 I used to navigate to various project folders in Source Control Explorer and double click the vbproj file and it would add it to my current Solution (or create a new solution if there wasn't one). The functionality in VS2010 seems to be that when I do this it closes my current Solution and opens the new project on its own.

Is there any way to get the VS2008 functionality back? I know I can right click on my Solution and *Add->Existing Project...*, but that takes a lot longer. I've tried Googling this but have come up blank.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this beaviour was taken out from VS between 2008 and 2010. In 2010 when you double-click a *.csproj or *.vbproj file it will always open it up in a "temporary solution".

This gets annoying when comparing diffs between local changes to your project file... in my view VS should open it in the editor if anything. /rant

Comment: Accepted as answer here, but not in my heart. Microsoft, you've hurt me.